# Please Help. Fail with error 'Min return not reached'

Tags: etherscan

Does anyone know how to solve this? This is the first time I use Metamask to swap ShibaInu, however it's failed.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa9a150efcb8ed43cdac2c30ff4a7c7ea551716d2b8449326f66d6826fea99507

Comment: I don't know Shibalnu, and the contract source code is not verified, so it's hard to say what the error message really means. I guess it indicates that you've used a slippage setting that was too low for this swap.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Any updates would be appreciated

Comment: Just had the same thing happen to me. A $102 transaction fee was taken from me, but the swap failed. Did not use all the gas. I am new to this. Are the fees gone or recoverable?

Comment: Same happened to me .75 is gone. It metamask it says completed but $0.00 balance. All the gas wasn’t used. I got fucked out of .75 in gas and $700 in profits

Comment: I think it is related to the  slippage tolerance, "By setting slippage tolerance, you basically set a limit on how many tokens you will accept, whether higher or lower than the rate shown in the interface"

Comment: the tx fees are sadly lost

Comment: From the trace at https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/main/0xa9a150efcb8ed43cdac2c30ff4a7c7ea551716d2b8449326f66d6826fea99507 it appears the contract doesn't arrives at a condition error.